# Google VR and Firefox 56 not working

Tags: firefox, google-vr

i updated my Firefox to version 56 and now the Google VR Image is now no more movable.

I can't drag the 360 degree image in Firefox.

Here ist a small preview on Codepen:
codepen.io/htmlr/pen/ryxgap?q=vrview&limit=all&type=type-pens

Can anyone help me? On Chrome,IE and the old Firefox Version it is working.

Only on the newest version of Firefox it's not working.
Thanks

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: "not working" is not a good problem statement. Do some debugging. Narrow the problem down. Ask a more specific question.